# After uninstalling Samba, can no longer access Windows network

Tags: networking, samba, shared-folders, workgroup

Ubuntu 20.04; local network with one Windows 7 and one Windows 8 machine, on a workgroup

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. At first I was able to see the Windows network and access the shared Windows machines/folders via Nemo or Nautilus without any problems.

Then, by mistake, I installed Samba Server per the steps here:

> https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#1-overview

I was still able to access the network after this.

I then uninstalled Samba using this command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove samba samba-common
```

After this, I can no longer access the network, let alone any specific machines. When clicking on Windows Network in Nautilus or Nemo I get:

> Unable to mount location - Failed to retrieve share list from server

What do I do to get network access back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure that you still have `samba-client` package installed:

```
sudo apt install samba-client
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!